# Visual Studio installer project - keep file while uninstall

Tags: visual-studio, installation, windows-installer, uninstallation

I am using Visual Studio Installer Projects to generate MSI files, it includes create log folder when it doesn't exist. When uninstall the program, that log folder and files inside will also deleted. Is there a way to keep those log folder and files during uninstall?